# Is it possible to assign a static function to a public member function during a class's construction?

Tags: c++

```
    CursorMove::CursorMove(char& dir)
    {
        if(dir == 'd')
        {
            this->execute = CursorMove::moveRight;
        }
        else if(dir == 'a')
        {
            this->execute = CursorMove::moveLeft;
        }
        else if(dir == 'w')
        {
            this->execute = CursorMove::moveUp;
        }
        else if(dir == 's')
        {
            this->execute = CursorMove::moveDown;
        }
    }
```

I am currently working on a CS project where we have to be able to move a cursor using the keyboard. The professor wants this to be done via classes because we will be using a while loop to constantly check for user input and then just have a single parent class whose execute will be called. Each unique execute belonging to its own class. I thought it might be easier to try to combine the commands for cursor movement into one. My idea for this was to use public static functions named moveRight, moveLeft, moveUp, and moveDown who all have the same parameters as execute be assigned accordingly to execute during construction. Which one determined by a parameter called "dir".

The error I am currently getting is "reference to non-static member function must be called." Rather than solve the error, I am more curious on whether or not this is a feasible idea or if I am better off just ignoring it and just making a class for each one.

Comment: What you are asking for can be done only if `execute` is declared as a [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), or at least as a plain ordinary [function pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer).  But not if it is implemented as an actual class method of its own.

Comment: There’s no reason for the `&` in `char&` here.

Comment: You probably want to write `&CursorMove::moveRight` instead.

Comment: This is a smart idea. But I don't see any reason of using object oriented programming here. There seems just to have a need for a mapping between a user input and a list of commands.

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly fine and reasonable. If you're having a problem, present the [MCVE] you've been debugging the problem with so that we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

> I am more curious on whether or not this is a feasible idea or if I am better off just ignoring it and just making a class for each one.

The overall plan is feasible. It seems more of a C-style approach than C++, but the functionality is supported. How to make it work depends on your class declaration, but you said you were not interested in the "how" (but I will note that the "static" part affects the "how", not the feasibility).

You might want to think about "why", though. What you are doing is basically creating a one-member virtual function table, similar to what the compiler would generate if you declared a virtual function named `execute`, then declared derived classes to override that function. The compiler's version has some nice benefits, such as handling the case where `dir` is not one of the expected values (possibly via a compile-time error). What are the benefits you hope to obtain with your method?

Answer (score 0):

Does your code look something like this? If so, then this is working fine for me:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CursorMove
{
        public:
                int (*execute)(void);
                static int moveLeft();
                static int moveRight();
                static int moveUp();
                static int moveDown();

                CursorMove(char& dir);
};
int CursorMove::moveLeft()
{
        cout<<"in move left"<<endl;
        return 1;
}

int CursorMove::moveRight()
{
        cout<<"in move Right"<<endl;
        return 1;
}

int CursorMove::moveUp()
{
        cout<<"in move Up"<<endl;
        return 1;
}

int CursorMove::moveDown()
{
        cout<<"in move Down"<<endl;
        return 1;
}

CursorMove::CursorMove(char& dir)
{
        if(dir == 'd')
        {
                this->execute = CursorMove::moveRight;
        }
        else if(dir == 'a')
        {
                this->execute = CursorMove::moveLeft;
        }
        else if(dir == 'w')
        {
                this->execute = CursorMove::moveUp;
        }
        else if(dir == 's')
        {
                this->execute = CursorMove::moveDown;
        }
}

int main()
{
        char dir = 'a';
        CursorMove *obj = new CursorMove(dir);
        obj->execute();
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: Missing `delete`, but `new` is unneeded.

Comment: Please describe the solution in the answer, don't just post code. The code should be used to clarify the answer.

Comment: Point taken @MaartenBodewes This was my first post in Stack Overflow community. Will keep this is mind on my future posts. Thanks.

Comment: No problem and a belated welcome Indranil; I see your other posts have performed considerably better :)